# Generate HTML to Pdf using iTextSharp with table border

Tags: c#, itext

I want to add bottom and top border of table contents. I have use ItextSharp.dll.
All style properties are working using following code But border properties are not working.
-- I try this code but it is not working for border properties

```
styles.LoadTagStyle("tr", "border-bottom-color", "Yellow");
styles.LoadTagStyle("tr", "border-bottom-width", "2px");
styles.LoadStyle("topBorder", "border-top-width", "2px");
styles.LoadStyle("topBorder", "border-top-color", "#985623");
```

If itextSharp is not support that properties then give any other way but using HTMl

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this

```
<table border="1">
```

hope it will work

try with the following

for all cell of first row

```
 cell.Border =  PdfCell.TOP_BORDER
```

for all cell of last row

```
cell.Border =  PdfCell.BOTTOM_BORDER
```

just do it for the every first row cell and every last row cell and u will get border at bottom and top of the table

Comment: yes , it is working But I want to only Bottom and top border of table.

Comment: I have used string='<table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>'. I have read this string .
So How to use cell.Border =  PdfCell.TOP_BORDER ??